# Windows 10 hotspot share WIFI connected to a VPN with another device

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, hotspot

I tried to share my Windows 10 laptop Wifi (connected to SSTP VPN) with my Ipad, but when i connected to the hotspot on my Ipad i can't reach the VPN intranet only the internet.

The VPN is working fine on Windows 10, using the VPN with split tunnel.

The goal is to use the VPN intranet on my Ipad, it's possible somehow because i downloaded the connectify app and create the hotspot with it and it's working fine, but i want to achieve it Windows native if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, needed to share the VPN adapter in: properties/sharing/

Check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection"

Home neworking connection: Wi-fi